# Tastypie GET manyTomany error

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a problem while using Tastypie with a very normal m2m relation.
In my (simplified) models:

```
class Promos(models.Model):
    promo_id = UUIDField(auto=True, unique=True, primary_key=True, null = False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400, default='title', null = False)
    text = models.TextField(max_length = 10000, null = False, default='text')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(CatPromos, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(null = False, default=False)

class CatPromos(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 10, unique=True, default='NoCat')
```

In my Resources:

```
class PromosResource(ModelResource):
    category =  fields.ForeignKey(CatPromosResource, 'category', full=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        object_class = Promos
        queryset = Promos.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        include_resource_uri = True
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        always_return_data = False
        filtering = {"category":ALL_WITH_RELATIONS}

    def get_object_list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Promos.objects.filter(active=True)   

class CatPromosResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        object_class = CatPromos
        queryset = CatPromos.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        include_resource_uri = True
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        always_return_data = False
        filtering = {"description":ALL}
        detail_uri_name = "_pk_val"
```

What I want is to GET a list of Promos, filtering by description like www.server.com/api/v1/promos?format=json&category__description=XXX

First, note that "detail_uri_name" int the Meta class of CatPromosResource. Tastypie (last version) kept crashing because of some problem with the detail_uri_name. Default is "pk" but the object who uses it needs "_pk_val". That, I realized after some debugging. 
But the problem now is that whenever I call GET with the uri above the server crashes with this message:

```
"invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''", 
"traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last): 
File \"...python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 202, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File \"...python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 441, in dispatch_list
    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)
File \"...python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 474, in dispatch
    response = method(request, **kwargs)
File \".../python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1135, in get_list       to_be_serialized[self._meta.collection_name] = [self.full_dehydrate(bundle) for bundle in bundles]
File \".../python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 739, in full_dehydrate
    bundle.data[field_name] = field_object.dehydrate(bundle)\  
File \".../python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 653, in dehydrate   
    return self.dehydrate_related(fk_bundle, self.fk_resource) 
File \".../python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 520, in dehydrate_related
    return related_resource.full_dehydrate(bundle) 
File \".../python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 739, in full_dehydrate
    bundle.data[field_name] = field_object.dehydrate(bundle)  
File \".../python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 121, in dehydrate    
    return self.convert(current_object)  
File \".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 220, in convert    
    return int(value)\n\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''\n"}
```

I'm lost here. I dont know what to do. I have tracked the call through the code but I dont know how to solve it. If anyone knows how to face this problem, or the correct way to implement a GET call with a m2m related relation, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
category =  fields.ToManyField(CatPromosResource, 'category', null=True)
```

Instead:

```
category =  fields.ForeignKey(CatPromosResource, 'category', full=True, null=True)
```

Also, this could help you:

http://eugene-yeo.me/2012/12/4/django-tastypie-manytomany-through-part-2/